# Listbox showing second item first

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am currently sitting on a Silverlight-Listbox and have some 
trouble getting my listBox right.

Its (visually) starts from the second item. 
I have to scroll up to see the first one.

Why is this happening and how could I fix this?

```
<ListBox x:Name="ServingsList" 
        Foreground="White" 
        Background="#FFB88A8A" 
        SelectionChanged="servingSelected" 
        Margin="0,0,0,297">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Height="70" Width="432">
                <Rectangle x:Name="Linie" 
               Fill="#FF8D8D8D" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
               Height="2" 
               StrokeThickness="0" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               Width="380" 
               Margin="0,-30,0,0" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="ServingTitel" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               Text="{Binding name}" 
               FontSize="21.333" 
               Margin="50,-60,0,0" />
                <Image x:Name="Ribbon" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
               Height="30" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               Width="151" 
               Source="/TEX/GrayRibbon.png" 
               Stretch="UniformToFill" 
               Margin="0,-60,0,0" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="Kcal" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               Text="{Binding kalorien]}" 
               FontSize="18.667" 
               Height="23" 
               Margin="0,-92,8,0" 
               TextAlignment="Right" />
                <Button Content="1" 
               Width="55" Height="55" 
               BorderThickness="3" 
               FontSize="18.667" 
               Padding="-1,-2,0,0" 
               Margin="-400,-87,0,0" 
               FontWeight="Bold" 
               Click="servingButtonClicked" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your `Margin` values - in the main list you're putting 297 pixels of whitespace below your list box. Other elements have weird values too. Expression Blend sometimes messes with the Margins if you change from a StackPanel to a Grid.

e.g:
    Margin="0,0,0,297">

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see your point. I checked the margins and played around a little. No change?

Comment: Try changing *all* your margins `Margin="0,0,0,0"`. It should bring back your first item although it will mess up the alignment of the other elements.